# KeystoneJsS: S3 filetype path for every item

Tags: keystonejs

I want to save my file to S3 and every item will have it own path, such as `base/item._id/filename`. How does one accomplish this?

It seems the filename is auto generated and the option doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Keystone's `Types.S3File` type has a `filename` option that you can set to a custom function in order to determine your own file name. [Documentation Link](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-s3file)

```
{
    type: Types.S3File,
    filename: function(item, filename) {
        // prefix file name with object id
        return item._id + '-' + filename;
    }
}
```

`item` has all the properties of the current item, so you could set it to `item.name` if that value exists.

Comment: Keystone moved to a centralized `Types.File` type with Keystone 4. You'll need to use their [Amazon S3 storage adapter](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-storage-adapter-s3) when creating your schema. It also appears as though the `generateFilename` function does not receive a reference to the item to be updated in Keystone 4, though. [More reading](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/wiki/File-Fields-Upgrade-Guide)

Comment: yes, i am using s3 adpter and it is working. but i want to have different sub-dir for different item. how to do it? s3: {
    path: 'uploads',
    headers: {
      'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
    },
  }, this will upload to /upload, i want /upload/item_id/xxx

Comment: I don't think that would be possible, since instantiating the adapter sets the directory for you and there isn't a way to change it later. There is a `path` option on the model, but it only expects a `String`, not a `Function`, so there is no way to dynamically generate the folder name, only the file name. [This](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/lib/storage/adapters/fs) is the Keystone 4 Filesystem adapter.

Comment: I believe so; the `filename` function in Keystone 3 used to pass a reference to the item being updated, but it no longer does that.